# sh scripting: string to array

Tags: arrays, string, shell, scripting, sh

I found similar answers for bash, but not for sh so I'm asking.

I have a $STRING which contains something like "Jun01 Jun02 Jun03 Jun04". I would like to put this into an array such that ${ARRAY[0]} is "Jun01", ${ARRAY[1]} is "Jun02", etc.

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really handle arrays natively in the standard (Bourne) shell.

See [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch45_34.htm) for more details.

> The C shell ( 47.5 ) , awk ( 33.11 ) , the Korn shell, and some other
>   UNIX command interpreters have built-in array support. The standard
>   Bourne shell doesn't, though its command line is a sort-of array that
>   you can store with the set ( 44.19 ) command - and get stored values
>   through $1 , $2 , etc.

I would try and use bash (as you've identified) or a more fully featured scripting language such as [Perl](http://www.perl.com) (no doubt others will suggest their favourites!)

Comment: Ok I guess I'll go with bash.

Answer (score 1):

sh does not have arrays, but the following hack is often adequate:

```
set $STRING
for x; do eval "ARRAY_$((i++))='$x'"; done
```

Now, (assuming `i` was unset or 0 to begin with), `$ARRAY_0` has the value `Jun01`, `$ARRAY_1` is `Jun02`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with the positional parameters: they're array-like.

```
set -- $STRING   # no quotes here
echo $1
echo $2
# etc
```